# Grouping for 5 variable k-map

Tags: karnaugh-map

Below is the K-map for 5(ZABCD) variables for a particular output namely Jb.
Noticed the "1" I highlighted, how should I group them? The "x" represent don't care term.

[image]

Should I group them in blue to maximize the number of variables?
[image]

Or group them in green since it involve two group in different box

[image]

Comment: You almost always want to group maximally in order to require fewer signals. You don't mention it, but I assume you also are finding at least two groups with eight boxes in them, yes?

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation, yeah I am not sure whether to group maximally or find the group that involves two boxes. Thank for pointing out.

Comment: "The K-map on the left side represents Z=1 and the right k-map represents Z=1" : not clear what you mean. Please edit.